# Java: gc.drawimage and transparency

Tags: java, drawimage

I am creating custom SWT widget but I have got problem with transparency. My class extends canvas, I have got png with alpha image in my resources, when I simply write:

```
this.setBackgroundImage(Colors.getMenuButton()); //getMenuButton returns Image object
```

everything works ok (with transparency), but my object has to be resizeable so I decided to create funcion:

```
protected Image BGHelper(Image src) {
    Image i2 = new Image(Display.getDefault(),2,26);
    GC gc2 = new GC(i2);

    Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(),this.getBounds().width,26);
    GC gc = new GC(image);
    gc.drawImage(src, 0, 0, 3, 25, 0, 0, 3, 26);
    gc2.drawImage(src, 3, 0, 2, 25, 0, 0, 2, 26);
    gc.drawImage(i2, 0, 0, 2, 25, 3, 0, this.getBounds().width-6, 26);
    gc.drawImage(src,53, 0, 3, 26, this.getBounds().width-3, 0, 3, 26);
    gc.dispose();
    gc2.dispose();
    return image;   
}
```

it cuts left border from source and paste into result, cut center from source, resize and paste into result, cut right border from source and paste into result. Resizing works *but* there is no transparency (white pixel). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at following doc.It might help you to solve your issue.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency